# How to get current object row/column

Tags: c#, object, grid, rows

I am now making a game which an object should move one row/column according to the arror key which was pressed.
For example, I want to write the commend " Grid.SetColumn(myObject,currentColumn +1); " , I just need to know how I get the currentColumn..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep in you code a global var which contain the current position of your object.

so you can say that your object is at that place :) don't forget to update the position.